# Why 2 expanded widgets' widths not equal

Tags: flutter

Why 2 expanded widgets' widths not equal
[image]

Between the Personal widget and Sick Widget. You will see the number zero text that does not align with the personal widget.

So I find the widget tree of the personal widget to take 73 widths while the sick widget takes 100 widths.

[image]

```
return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, right: 4.0, left: 4.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: StatusItem(
                  img: Assets.images.svgIcons.icPersonal.svg(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                  label: translations.personalText,
                  total: personalLeave,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: StatusItem(
                  img: Assets.images.svgIcons.icSwitch.svg(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    color: FigmaColors.slateColor,
                  ),
                  label: translations.switchText,
                  total: switchHoliday,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 14.0,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: StatusItem(
                  img: Assets.images.svgIcons.icSick.svg(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                  label: translations.sickText,
                  total: sickLeave,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container())
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Can you explain and fix this one?

Comment: what is StatusItem?

Answer (score 3):

> [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) is A widget that expands so that the child fills the
> available space.

in first `Row` you have 3 children :

- `Expanded` , `SizedBox`, and `Expanded`
  so they will divide by 2 space after reduced the `Sizedbox` width

in second `Row` your there is no `SizedBox` that take any space. thats why `Expanded` will divide by 2 all the space

> how wo fix: add same size of `SizeBox` to the second `Row`

```
Row(
  children:[
   Expanded(),
   SizedBox(width:8),
   Expanded(),
])
```